# Unable to resolve additional project configuration

Tags: gradle

In my build.gradle I have this dependencies, during the build its not downloading the dependencies file from mule, and giving error message.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.mule.modules:mule-apikit-module:1.1.9'    
    testImplementation 'com.mulesoft.munit:munit-runner:2.1.5'
    testImplementation 'com.mulesoft.munit:munit-tools:2.1.5'    
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.5.8'
}
```

**Error message**

> Warning:root project  Unable to resolve additional project
>   configuration. Details: org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException:
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration
>   ':runtimeClasspath'. Caused by:
>   org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find
>   mule-apikit-module-1.1.9.jar
>   (org.mule.modules:mule-apikit-module:1.1.9). Searched in the following
>   locations:
>       https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/org/mule/modules/mule-apikit-module/1.1.9/mule-apikit-module-1.1.9.jar

When I look at the Mule site, jar has `-mule-plugin` string added to the name.

https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/mule/modules/mule-apikit-module/1.1.9/mule-apikit-module-1.1.9-mule-plugin.jar

How can I update my build.gradle to download this dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

The `-mule-plugin` part is a classifier. Not sure why they are using a classifier since it is the only artifact for that coordinate, but you can specify it like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.mule.modules:mule-apikit-module:1.1.9:mule-plugin'
}
```